# How to insert items in a List

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

In the coding below I am inserting items into a `datagrid` from a `combobox`.

```
private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as ExtraDisplayItems;

        if (item != null)
        {
            var displayItem = new List<ExtraDisplayItems>
            {
                new ExtraDisplayItems 
                {                            
                    ItemId = item.ItemId, 
                    ItemCode = item.ItemCode, 
                    ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription, 
                    ItemSellingPrice = item.ItemSellingPrice,
                    displayItems = item.displayItems //Always null?
                }
            };
            dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    btnRemoveAllExtras.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I've created a variable in my class below, where I want to be able to access the items in a different method and get the **Sum** total of my *ItemSellingPrice*.

My class:

```
public class ExtraDisplayItems
{
    public List<ExtraDisplayItems> displayItems;

    public int ItemId { get; set; }    
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }    
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }    
    public double? ItemSellingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now my issue is that in the top method where I am inserting the items into the datagrid, my `displayItems` variable is always **null** for some reason. Is there some special way that I need to load the items into the `displayItems` list in my class?

Comment: Have you tried by instantiating the displayItems?

Comment: @Turbulence - Thank you for the reply! :) How would I go about doing this? May you show me an example please?

Comment: Here you go
    `public ExtraDisplayItems(){ this.displayItems=new List<ExtraDisplayItems>();}`

Comment: Thank you! Should I insert this inside my method or somewhere else?

Comment: It's the constructor for ExtraDisplayItems class. Use it there

Comment: Anyway, instantiating it won't fill the collection, you'll have an empty list instead... What are you trying to achieve? Why is there a list of items inside an item? Is that some kind of data tree?

Comment: @almulo - I want to access the `var displayItem` in another method so that I can calculate the total **Sum** of the` ItemSellingPrice` that was inserted in my datagrid. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you'll store the whole list of items in each one of them? Mmmh, sounds like an overkill... You should probably be storing the collection in some var in you code before assigning it to your DataGrid, and using that var to calculate the sum.

Comment: You could benefit a lot from MVVM... WPF really works better when you use viewmodels and Bindings :P

Comment: (Also, I don't know if it's a typo, but in the code you've posted, you're not using `displayItem` for anything... You just create it and then ignore it :P)

Comment: @almulo - I think what I am trying to do(:P), is that I am adding the items from the `combobox` into the `datagrid` so that I can calculate _only_ the item's that in the datagid and not in the whole class. Haha and I just noticed that I didn't really need the `var displayItem`, so I removed it. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the whole collection of selected items on each item you add to the DataGrid. You can retrieve the collection from the DataGrid itself, and you can do so using a calculated property like this, for instance (you may need to add `System.Linq` to your usings):

```
private IEnumerable<ExtraDisplayItems> SelectedDisplayItems
{
    get
    {
        return dgAddExtras.Items.Cast<ExtraDisplayItems>();
    }
}
```

That way, you can remove the list from the `ExtraDisplayItems` class.

```
public class ExtraDisplayItems
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }    
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }    
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }    
    public double? ItemSellingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Your `SelectionChanged` method would end up like this:

```
private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // You're not using TSC, so you don't need this either
    //using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    //{
        var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as ExtraDisplayItems;

        if (item != null)
        {
            dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
        }
    //}
    btnRemoveAllExtras.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And in your other method that needs to calculate the sum of `ItemSellingPrice`, you just need to use the calculated property.

```
private void YourOtherMethod()
{
    // do stuff

    var sum = SelectedDisplayItems.Sum(item => item.ItemSellingPrice ?? 0); // Since ItemSellingPrice can be null, use 0 instead

    // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: Hahaha woooow!!! I've struggled so long with this issue and now you've given me the answer. It works perfectly! Thank you so so much almulo!! :D Best answer out of all the questions I had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem` is not of type `ExtraDisplayItems`. It is either null or a different type

Comment: Thank you for the answer Glen, but this still gives my `displayItems` a value of **null** .